# Sed Match & Replace already escaped URLs (https:/\/\eample.com\/wp-content\/themes/image/picture.png)

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I've been trying to parse through a large number of json files within subdirectories and search-replace the URLs/strings. No matter what I try I can't seem to get sed to actually make any changes within the files.

The strings must be in this format as it's what's required in the json files. My reasoning for this is there could be other image urls within other files with different tags I hadn't accounted for and therefore this would catch all basically.

In my current environment, I don't have jq and can't install it, but I could move these files somewhere else and use jq or python or whatever...

Here's the general structure of the files, I believe I am piping the correct files, just sed not playing nice.

```
payloads/themes/settings/en/file1
                           /file2
                           /file..N
                        /fr/file1
                           /file2
                           /file..N
                        /de/file1
                           /file2
                           /file..N
```

```
function repair_theme_settings() {
  FIND=("https:\/\/example.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/01\/logo-272-png8-64.png" \
  "https:\/\/example.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/01\/logo-retina.png" \
  "https:\/\/example.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/01\/favicon.png" \
  "https:\/\/example.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/01\/logo-mobile.png" \
  "https:\/\/example.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/01\/logo-mobile-retina.png" \
  "https:\/\/example.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/01\/iOS-76.png" \
  "https:\/\/example.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/01\/iOS-114.png" \
  "https:\/\/example.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/01\/iOS-120.png" \
  "https:\/\/example.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/01\/iOS-144.png" \
  "https:\/\/example.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/01\/iOS-152.png" \
  "https:\/\/example.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/01\/background.jpg" \
  "2019 MY WEB SITE")

  REPLACE=("https:\/\/example.com\/wp-content\/themes\/my-theme\/images\/logo.png" \
  "https:\/\/example.com\/wp-content\/themes\/my-theme\/images\/logo-retina.png" \
  "https:\/\/example.com\/wp-content\/themes\/my-theme\/images\/favicon.png" \
  "https:\/\/example.com\/wp-content\/themes\/my-theme\/images\/logo-mobile.png" \
  "https:\/\/example.com\/wp-content\/themes\/my-theme\/images\/logo-mobile-retina.png" \
  "https:\/\/example.com\/wp-content\/themes\/my-theme\/images\/iOS-76.png" \
  "https:\/\/example.com\/wp-content\/themes\/my-theme\/images\/iOS-114.png" \
  "https:\/\/example.com\/wp-content\/themes\/my-theme\/images\/iOS-120.png" \
  "https:\/\/example.com\/wp-content\/themes\/my-theme\/images\/iOS-144.png" \
  "https:\/\/example.com\/wp-content\/themes\/my-theme\/images\/iOS-152.png" \
  "https:\/\/example.com\/wp-content\/themes\/my-theme\/images\/background.jpg" \
  "2021 MY WEB SITE")

  i="0"
  while [ $i -lt 12 ]
  do
    FIND_THIS=${FIND[i]}
    # echo "FIND THIS: "$FIND_THIS
    REPLACE_THIS=${REPLACE[i]}
    # echo "REPLACE THIS: "$REPLACE_THIS
    find payloads/themes/settings/ -type f | xargs sed -i 's|'"$FIND_THIS"'|'"$REPLACE_THIS"'|g'
    i=$[$i+1]
  done
}
```

Here's an example section within the json file:

```
"tds_logo_upload_r":"https:\/\/exmaple.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/01\/logo-retina.png","tds_favicon_upload":"https:\/\/example.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/01\/favicon.png",
```

I've tried `'s|'"$FIND_THIS"'|'"$REPLACE_THIS"'|g'` and `"s|$FIND_THIS|$REPLACE_THIS|g"` Now I am wondering if the escaped slashes is an issue? or maybe it's how I am using the variable substitution?

I don't get any error message with the above code, just values aren't changing within the files.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

I've since checked and noticed that plain.txt version containing the same data in a simple array structure has updated, but without escaping slashes.

This is the changed output from non-json version:

```
  'tds_logo_upload' => 'https://example.com/wp-content/themes/my-theme/images/logo.png',
  'tds_logo_upload_r' => 'https://example.com/wp-content/themes/my-theme/images/logo-retina.png',
  'tds_favicon_upload' => 'https://example.com/wp-content/themes/my-theme/images/favicon.png',
```

So the script works, but not on the json files with the escaped urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be overthinking. Please try instead something like:

```
sed -i -E 's#(https:\\\/\\\/example\.com\\\/wp-content\\\/)uploads\\\/2021\\\/01\\\/([^/]+\.(jpg|png))#\1themes\\/my-theme\\/images\\/\2#g' payloads/themes/settings/*.json
```

- `Sed` requires a lot of backslashes to escape a backslash character itself.
  Sometimes it is a mess.
- It is not a good idea to store the search pattern and the replacement list
  in a variable because you need to put much more backslashes in the
  variable interpolation in the `bash` command line.
- You are enclosing the `sed` command which includes the variables with
  single quotes. Then the variable interpolation does not work.

Comment: There is no need to escape the slashes when you use a separator which isn't a slash. The slash character has no special meaning to the regex engine proper; it simply matches itself.

Comment: @tripleee thank you for the comment. You're right, but please note the "example section within the json file" by the OP already includes a backslash in front of a slash. Then we need to escape the backslash, not the slash.

Comment: I'm guessing that's a mistake on their part; the expected output doesn't contain any backslashes.

Comment: @tripleee honestly I too am in doubt about the existence of the backslashes in the original json file. I just followed it literally.

Comment: Honestly, the backslashes are present in the json files, it's weird and annoying. It's effectively a dump of some cell of data from wp_options with a big serial in it. But as I export the data using wp-cli it allows you to select a format. I picked json and it has the escaped slashes everywhere,  the direct dump format version doesn't escape any slashes which is why my code works for the non-json formatted files of same data. I'll try the extra escaping you offered @tshiono in a bit, thank you both for comments.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed comment. I have tested my code with your backslashed example and it produces the expected output (except for the possible typo in the example "exmaple"). Please try my code and if you have any questions, let me know. Good luck.

Comment: This worked like a charm for most the images, thank you! Please just adjust it to take account of the language folders to be exact to the question so /*/*.json

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Good to know it works. BTW can you elaborate on the meaning of "the language folders to be exact to the question"? Should I specify or change the directory path to the json files? Or is it better to use `find` command as described in your question?